# Magento 1.7.0.2 Inserting remarketing tags on category page using Anaraky plugin

Tags: magento-1.7, google-analytics, meta-tags

I'm trying to insert some dynamic remarketing tag on a Magento 1.7.0.2 page using a free plugin called [Anaraky](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/anaraky-gdrt-google-dynamic-remarketing-tag-for-magento.html).

The plugin works well enough (for a free plugin), but I am having trouble with one of Google's requirements:

I must include a tag called `ecomm_prodid` before the `</body>` tag on every page of my site, this `ecomm_prodid` must show the SKU for each product shown on a page. So for example if a category page shows 3 products, the tag will be written as

`ecomm_prodid: ["Prod1","Prod2","Prod3"],`

Here's the code I'm trying to use

```
 case 'category':
            $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
            $items = $category->getAllVisibleItems();

            if (count($items) > 0) {
                $data  = array();
                foreach ($items as $item)
                {
                    $data[0][] = $this->getEcommProdid($item->getProduct());
                    $data[1][] = (int)$item->getQty();

                }

                $params = array(
                    'ecomm_prodid' => $data[0],
                    'ecomm_pagetype' => 'category',
                    'ecomm_quantity' => $data[1],

                );
            }
            else
                $params = array( 'ecomm_pagetype' => 'other' );

            unset($cart, $items, $item, $data);
            break;
```

But it is not working.

My question is, how should I modify this script so that it detects which products are being show on a page and then writes their skus on the `ecomm_prodid` tag?